# Where can I practice MITM raw binary protocols?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, vulnerability-scanners

I want to try practicing MITMing raw TCP binary protocols as well as MITMing HTTP protocol. What is the best way to do this? Are there any specific tools which help me do this? Like wireshark or ZAP or Burp suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/), formerly known as *BackTrack*, which has numerous penetration testing tools pre-installed. You could set up either a dedicated machine, or run the OS in a virtualized environment (e.g. VMWare Player).

The tool of most use to you would probably be [Ettercap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap_%28computing%29). Wireshark is also included in Kali.

If your computer has multiple [NICs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller), you could start another virtual machine that would act as client. If your computer has only one NIC, you'll need another machine with a network interface (not necessarily a personal computer).

Comment: About the NICs, can't I just initialize the machine to a new MAC address in VirtualBox? Also, it'd be great if you could provide some pointers on how this is done. Thanks!

Comment: You'll notice that this isn't possible. A NIC can only have _one_ MAC address, not two. You effectively need two NICs, each of which you would assign to another virtual machine (easy with VMWare Player - but I haven't used other VM software). You can find more helpful information on [Kali's documentation web site](http://docs.kali.org/), and [this page](http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/hacking-tutorial/kali-linux-man-middle-attack) on [hacking-tutorial.com](http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/) might be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Burp suite is by far one of the best tools to learn about http protocols and it can also help you in MITMing attacks.

Comment: What would you say about tools like ZAP, WebScarb, Mallory?

Comment: ZAP,WebScarab and Mallory have functions common to burp. It all depends on the pentester that what tool he/she chooses. So you can also use ZAP that is recommended by OWASP as long as it fulfils your requirements.